# why my wpf application get value -2097152 when capture Network card speeds?

Tags: wpf, string, int64, int32

I have developed an application which one capture network card speeds,i use below code to get data:

```
NetworkInterface nic = nicArr[0];
IPv4InterfaceStatistics interfaceStats = nic.GetIPv4Statistics();
Int64 bytesSentSpeed = (Int64)(interfaceStats.BytesSent - uploadSpeed) / 1024;
uploadSpeed = double.Parse(interfaceStats.BytesSent.ToString());
Int64 bytesReceivedSpeed = (int)(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - downloadSpeed) / 1024;
downloadSpeed = double.Parse(interfaceStats.BytesReceived.ToString());
UpDownSpeed.Add("UpSpeed", bytesSentSpeed.ToString());
UpDownSpeed.Add("DownSpeed", bytesReceivedSpeed.ToString());
```

and then i get value:

```
UpDpwnSpeed["UpSpeed"].ToString()
```

why i get a number -2097152?

Comment: looks like an over flow exception. But you are not showing the whole picture: the definitions for `uploadSpeed` and `downloadSpeed` are missing, and is this inside a while loop?

Comment: It's not inside a loop.It's an over flow exception problem,change int to Int64,i resolve this problem,thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have `uploadSpeed` and `downloadSpeed` as `float`, for `bytesReceivedSpeed` you cast the expression to to `int`, so if you have the value in `(interfaceStats.BytesReceived - downloadSpeed)` bigger as 2147483647(`int.MaxValue`), then you become a negative value on down cast `(int)`.
Make all operations as float and just format value for your dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your help !  I am change int to Int64,then i solve this problem.